# Condition on proper lower sections on total ordering for it to be a well-ordering

Tags: elementary-set-theory, well-orders

Context: trying to get someone else to do my thinking for me.

Reference: Smullyan and Fitting: *Set Theory and the Continuum Problem* (rev ed. 2010)

Chapter $4$: Superinduction, Well-Ordering and Choice: $\S 1$: Introduction to Well-Ordering

We are looking at Exercise $1.2$.

> For a linear ordering $\le$ on a class $A$, a subclass $L$ of $A$ is called a *lower section* of $A$ (with respect to $\le$, understood) if every element of $L$ is less than every element of $A$ not in $L$. A lower section $L$ of $A$ is called a *proper lower section* if it is non-empty and not the whole of $A$.

> Prove that a sufficient condition for a linear ordering $\le$ to be a *well* ordering of $A$ is that, for every proper lower section $L$ of $A$, there is a least element $x$ of $A$ not in $L$.

So, suppose $A$ is a class under $\le$ such that $\le$ has exactly the above property.

To demonstrate a well-ordering it is sufficient to show that every non-empty subclass of $A$ has a least element. Clearly $A \setminus L$ has a least element. But that's just $A \setminus L$. I can't get further by abstract thinking on the matter.

So I thought: what if I try to create a counterexample? What about the set of integers $\Bbb Z$ under the usual ordering? That's a linearly ordered set (and a set is a class innit).

Let $x$ be some element in $\Bbb Z$. Then the set $\{y \in \Bbb Z: y < x \}$ is a lower section of $\Bbb Z$ which has the above properties. That is, the element $x$ is itself that smallest element of $A \setminus L$.

Are there any other proper lower sections of $\Bbb Z$ which are *not* of the form $\{y \in \Bbb Z: y < x \}$? I can't see how such a proper lower section could be constructed.

But while it *appears* as though $\Bbb Z$ fulfils the conditions for $(\Bbb Z, \le)$ to be a well-ordered set, $\Bbb Z$ most patently is *not* a well-ordered set, because it does not have a smallest element.

There must be something I am missing.

Comment: You are right -- the problem is not correct as stated. Either require $A$ to have a least element, or, what amounts to the same thing, change the definition of "proper lower section" to allow $L$ to be empty.

Comment: I puzzled over this for a long time before hitting on the same counter-example.  However, I eventually became confident that the text is wrong.  I think that "sufficient" should be replaced by "necessary" -- the text is giving a property that well-ordered sets have.  I know that that makes the problem easy but most problems in the early chapters of this book are easy.